# Is there a naming convention for locale-specific static files?

Tags: internationalization, locale

I have some static resources (images and HTML files) that will be localized.  One piece of software I've seen do this is Apache, which appends the locale to the name; for example, `test_en_US.html` or `test_de_CH.html`.  I'm wondering whether this naming scheme is considered standard, or whether every project does it differently.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

While there is no documented standard for naming Localized files, I'd recommend using the format **filename[_language[ _country]]** where

- language is the [ISO-639](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_ISO_639-1_codes) 2 letter language code
- territory is the [ISO-3166](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_3166-1_alpha-2#Officially_assigned_code_elements) 2 letter country code

For example:

- myFile.txt (non-localized file)
- myFile_en.txt (localized for global English)
- myFile_en_US.txt (localized for US English)
- myFile_en_GB.txt (localized for UK English)

Why? This is the most typical format used by operating systems, globalization tools (such as Trados and WorldServer), and programming languages. So unless you have a particular fondness for a different format, I see no reason to deviate from what most other folks are doing. It may save you some integration headaches down the road.

Answer (score 1):

While there doesn't appear to a standard conventions as to *where* in the file name to place them, the international codes for language (e.g. "en") and region (e.g. "en-US") are both very common and very straightforward.  Variations I've seen, excluding "enUS" vs. "en_US" vs. "en-US":

- foo.enUS.ext
- foo.ext_enUS
- enUS.foo.ext
- foo/enUS.ext
- enUS/foo.ext
- *…ad nauseum*

I personally favor the first and last variants.  The former for grouping files by name/resource (good for situations in which a limited number of files need localized) and the latter for grouping files by locale (better for situations with a large number of localized files).

Answer (score 0):

You should always use the "de-facto" standard, which is the unix/posix way with `gettext`. And you shoud use `gettext` to make your localization!

Therefore one and only correct way is to use localization naming like this:

```
en
en_US
en_UK
```

Some applications and especially Java developers ar sometimes using the `en-US` (hyphenated instead than underscored) and it is ALL WRONG!!!

gettext standard is this and only this:

```
locale
 |_en_US
    |_LC_MESSAGES
      |_appname.mo
```

Where:

`locale` - Name of the directory, can vary but it is highly recommended to stay with "locale"-name

`en_US` - Any standard locale like *es_ES*, *es_PT*, ...

`LC_MESSAGES` - mandatory and cannot be changed!

appname.mo - msgfmt compiled appname.po file (appname is what ever you want)